# Java Script, CSS (Coursor AKA buttom)

Tags: javascript, html, css

Helo friends,
How to create a coursor that is at the same time a buttom, when you hover it over a certain object, it ceases to be a button and becomes just a coursor.
I hope to find a solution in these technologies JavaScript, css, html.
Thanks a lot in advance for your help.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xbTk0.gif)

Comment: So you want us to copy something somebody has already written. How about you check out the code on the page that you've seen the effect on. We aren't going to right the code for you though. You should at least show that you've tried to implement this.

Comment: Checkout the css [cursor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor) property, which supports setting an image as the cursor